# Spring RestTemplate returns null object when trying to deserialize nested list of object

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, deserialization

So this is the Json I am trying to convert to a Java bean

I am using jackson to bind JSON to my data objects

```
{
        "legend": {
            "id": "379ec5d8c",
            "name": "Stabil Koos",
            "payers": [{
                    "id": "ab1651df-b835-495558-a2a5-2e6d42f7a41e",
                    "ranking": 1,
                    "buyer": {
                        "id": "67a6359838-0fda-43a6-9e2b-51a7d399b6a1",
                        "nationality": "en",
                        "stats": {
                            "gameeCount": 16581,
                            "count": 99098
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "379ecw555d8c",
                    "ranking": 2,
                    "buyer": {
                        "id": "2b451d0eda-ab0c-4345660-be3f-6ba3bebf1f81",
                        "nationality": "no",
                        "stats": {
                            "gamerCount": 1182,
                            "count": 7113
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

My beans look like this ;

```
 public class League implements Serializable {

   private String id;
   private String name;
   @JsonUnwrapped
   private List<Payer> payers;

   // getters and setters
```

Payers bean :

```
  public class Payers implements Serializable {

      private String id;
      private long ranking;
      private Buyer buyer;

      // getters and setters
```

I am using Rest Template and postForObject in Junit

```
@Before
public void beforeTest() {
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    entity = new HttpEntity(REQUEST, headers);
}
```

And my final code to retrieve the object is :

```
@Test
public void retrieveData() {
    League league = restTemplate.postForObject(ENDPOINT_URL, entity, League.class);
    System.out.println(legend);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON you show is for an object that has a `league` property which is a `League` object and not a league object itself. You need an additional response class:

```
class LeagueResponse {
  private League league;

  League getLeague() { return league; }
}
```

and:

```
LeagueResponse leagueResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(ENDPOINT_URL, entity, LeagueResponse.class);
League league = leagueResponse.getLeague();
```

Comment: Thanks you so much P.J.Meisc. That was a quick fix you saved my day !